# XSL Sorting By Multiple Attributes?

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xpath

So suppose I have some data like this, where some of the nodes have an element called "idNumber" and some have one called "serialNumber":

```
<data>
    <product>
        <name> Chair </name>
        <idNumber> 12 </idNumber>
    </product>

    <product>
        <name> Table </name>
        <idNumber> 16 </idNumber>
    </product>

    <product>
        <name> Lamp </name>
        <serialNumber> 13 </serialNumber>
    </product>

    <product>
        <name> Fan </name>
        <idNumber> 10 </idNumber>
    </product>

    <product>
        <name> Desk </name>
        <serialNumber> 15 </serialNumber>
    </product>
</data>
```

I need to sort them by their number, whether it be idNumber or serialNumber; so the result would be:

Fan - 10

Chair - 12

Lamp -13

Desk -15

Table - 16

I tried using:

```
<xsl:sort select="idNumber"/>
<xsl:sort select="serialNumber"/>
```

However this doesn't work as I want because it tries sorting all by the first, even if it doesn't have that element. I need a way to sort that takes both into account and chooses the right one and orders them correctly. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `xsl:sort` instruction:

```
<xsl:sort select="concat(normalize-space(idNumber),normalize-space(serialNumber))" data-type="number"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<xsl:sort select="idNumber | serialNumber"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. Turns out my problem is a bit different than I originally thought. Basically each node has BOTH "idNumber" and "serialNumber", but sometimes one is empty (blank). Ideally I'd be able to say, "IF idNumber NOT Empty sort by idNumber, ELSE sort by serialNumber". Hope that makes sense. Anyway it seems you can't use conditions in sorts, so I'm at a loss as to what to do.

Comment: @Arcturus, can you provide an example when this `xsl:sort` produces unwanted result?

Comment: yes the problem is with "<xsl:sort select="idNumber | serialNumber"/>" is that if "idNumber" is blank, instead of using "serialNumber", it just puts that item at the beginning of the list because a blank space comes before anything else.